# Waste Management API - Authorization: Bearer problem

Tags: api, curl, post, postman

Im reading this documentation:

https://api.wm.com/howtotest/#make-an-api-call

And I want to make this test request in the postman:

```
curl -i https://apitest.wm.com/v1/helloworld \
-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhbnlvbmVAYW55LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6Ildhc3RlIG1hbmFnZW1lbnQgIHRlYW0iLCJqdGkiOiIwQkQyRTVDQkM2RDE2Mzc0RkNFQSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInNlbGYiLCJoZWxsb3dvcmxkIl0sImlhdCI6MTQ5MDg5ODk1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTIyNDM0OTU1fQ.O2k-senypXFZQwW4Ln3mBg60qzOSo-diPQWVfir3m6Q" \
-H "ClientId: 0BD2E5CBC6D16374FCEA" \
-H "Request-Tracking-Id: 12132"
```

But i recived response like this:

```
{
    "message": "'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhbnlvbmVAYW55LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6Ildhc3RlIG1hbmFnZW1lbnQgIHRlYW0iLCJqdGkiOiIwQkQyRTVDQkM2RDE2Mzc0RkNFQSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInNlbGYiLCJoZWxsb3dvcmxkIl0sImlhdCI6MTQ5MDg5ODk1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTIyNDM0OTU1fQ.O2k-senypXFZQwW4Ln3mBg60qzOSo-diPQWVfir3m6Q' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhbnlvbmVAYW55LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6Ildhc3RlIG1hbmFnZW1lbnQgIHRlYW0iLCJqdGkiOiIwQkQyRTVDQkM2RDE2Mzc0RkNFQSIsInNjb3BlIjpbInNlbGYiLCJoZWxsb3dvcmxkIl0sImlhdCI6MTQ5MDg5ODk1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTIyNDM0OTU1fQ.O2k-senypXFZQwW4Ln3mBg60qzOSo-diPQWVfir3m6Q'."
}
```

This is the example of their official documentation, how it can be it doesnt works, or I didnt do something good?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error message is potentially misleading. If you are using the test example you need to request a clientid and token from WM per the documentation.

From the documentation:

> With a valid access token and clientId, you are ready to make requests to Waste Management API.

Comment: I recived access token and clientId, but also I've got the same issue.

Comment: not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header:

Comment: Appears to be an error on their side, if you use CURL the returned errors indicated this. 

`x-amzn-ErrorType: IncompleteSignatureException
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront`

Comment: so what that means? How I can get the data?

Comment: Speak with the people who supply the API I guess. Not sure how else I can help sorry.